# Laravel Email Function - REST API

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, email

Quick Fire Question, I am using mail function of laravel 5.1, but it still gives me variable not defined error, I have debugged and checked the variable I am printing is valid.

```
$email_id = $users[0]['email_id'];
//i have checked $email_id by printing and it is working.

    Mail::send('emails.forgetpassword', ['title' => $title, 'name' => $name, 'content' => $content, 'link' => $link], function ($message)
                    {
                        $message->from('xyz@gmail.com', 'xyz Team');
                        $message->to($email_id);
                        $message->subject('xyz App - Forget Password');
                    });
```

I have checked the documentation I don't know what it is missing.
It throws me error at this line

```
$message->to($email_id);
```

I don't know why $email_id is already defined and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$email_id = $users[0]['email_id'];
//i have checked $email_id by printing and it is working.

Mail::send('emails.forgetpassword', 
    [
       'title' => $title, 
       'name' => $name, 
       'content' => $content, 
       'link' => $link
    ], 
    function ($message) use($email_id) {
         $message->from('xyz@gmail.com', 'xyz Team');
         $message->to($email_id);
         $message->subject('xyz App - Forget Password');
    }
);
```

You need to send email_id to anonymous function. it is undefined in anonymous function's scope

Comment: Okay worked but can u pls tell me a bit about anonymous function why I need that?

Comment: Because every function (not only anonymous function) has own scope. So anonymous function is like other function its scope is different from the parent function which anonymous function defined. So if you want to use a variable defined in parent you need to pass it to anonymous function. In php we can do that by use statement. http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Thanks, so probably we can say or use it as a callback function right?